# Swing loginpanel

Tags: java, eclipse, swing

I'm new to Swing and I'm trying to create an inlog screen with some textfield and buttons. When I run it, I get an empty screen, but once I resize the window, it starts working ... Does anyone know why?

code:

```
package ui_view;
import java.awt.BorderLayout;
import java.awt.Component;
import java.awt.GridBagConstraints;
import java.awt.GridBagLayout;
import java.awt.GridLayout;
import java.awt.image.BufferedImage;
import java.io.File;
import java.io.IOException;

import javax.imageio.ImageIO;
import javax.swing.ImageIcon;
import javax.swing.JFrame;
import javax.swing.JLabel;
import javax.swing.JPanel;
import javax.swing.JButton;
import javax.swing.JTextField;

public class InlogView extends JFrame{

    GridBagConstraints constraints;
    JPanel p = new JPanel();
    JPanel bp = new JPanel();
    JPanel img = new JPanel();
    JButton inlogButton;
    JButton cancelButton;
    JLabel gebruikersNaam;
    JTextField gebruikersInvoer;
    JLabel wachtwoord;
    JTextField wachtwoordInvoer;
    BufferedImage image;
    JLabel picLabel;

    public InlogView(){
        super("inlog");
        setDefaultCloseOperation(JFrame.EXIT_ON_CLOSE);
        setSize(370,300);
        add(img, BorderLayout.PAGE_START);
        add(p, BorderLayout.CENTER);
        add(bp, BorderLayout.PAGE_END);
        setVisible(true);
        setResizable(true);
    }

    public void maakInlogView() throws IOException{
        p.setLayout(new GridBagLayout());
        constraints = new GridBagConstraints();
        constraints.fill = GridBagConstraints.HORIZONTAL;

        gebruikersNaam = new JLabel("gebruikersnaam: ");
        changeConstraints(1,1,0,0);
        p.add(gebruikersNaam, getConstraints());

        gebruikersInvoer = new JTextField(10);
        changeConstraints(1,1,1,0);
        p.add(gebruikersInvoer, getConstraints());

        wachtwoord = new JLabel("wachtwoord: ");
        changeConstraints(1,1,0,1);
        p.add(wachtwoord, getConstraints());

        wachtwoordInvoer = new JTextField(10);
        changeConstraints(1,1,1,1);
        p.add(wachtwoordInvoer, getConstraints());

        inlogButton = new JButton("Aanmelden");
        cancelButton = new JButton("Cancel");

        bp.add(inlogButton);
        bp.add(cancelButton);

        image = ImageIO.read(new File("doc/14_1.png"));
        picLabel = new JLabel(new ImageIcon(image));
        img.add(picLabel);

    }

    protected void changeConstraints(int height, int width, int gridx, int gridy) {
        constraints.gridheight = height;
        constraints.gridwidth = width;
        constraints.gridx = gridx;
        constraints.gridy = gridy;
    }

    protected GridBagConstraints getConstraints() {
        return constraints;
    }


    public static void main(String args[]) throws IOException{
        InlogView inlog = new InlogView();
        inlog.maakInlogView();

    }
}
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Call `setVisible(true)` in `maakInlogView()` and not in the constructor.

Answer (score 0):

you have to call validate() on the JFrame or JPanel

in your case just add validate() after setResizable(true)

Comment: @ChenChen: no, this is not the correct solution. The solution is as Ian states, to call `setVisible(true)` **after** adding all components to your window. Best would be for you to call `maakInlogView()` inside the InlogView class constructor and before calling `setVisible(true)`.